# Change Kops deployment style

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I deployed a cluster of Kubernetes on AWS through the use of Kops. Like all those who have used Kops know, Kops places constraints in building a Kubernetes on AWS infrastructure (for example, when it goes to perform a multi-master installation what it does is create in each AZ of a region an AWS autoscaling group with a single instance EC2).

My question is: **is it possible to change the way in which it carries out the deployment?**

Specifically, I *would like a deployment with 3 Masters in each AZ, so that the number of Masters is 9*.

Suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`kops create cluster ...` should be able to spread the masters in different zones depending on the number. You need these two options when creating a cluster

```
--master-count int32               Set the number of masters.  Defaults to one master per master-zone
--master-zones strings             Zones in which to run masters (must be an odd number)
```

So in other words for example for 9 masters in 3 zones:

```
--master-count 9
--master-zones us-east-1d,us-east-1b,us-east-1c
```

More info in the [CLI options](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cli/kops_create_cluster.md).

Comment: Hi Rico. Thanks for your reply. Tomorrow I will try to deploy it with those instructions, and I will tell you if it works

Comment: Hi!! I haven't tried it, but I have found this discussion that seems to confirm your answer https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/732#issuecomment-297043008 I hope to try it in those days.